# Using available UserTransaction with hibernate JPA?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jboss

I have APP1 and APP2. App1 is deployed in JBoss5 and App2 will be in Tomcat7. I connect to APP1 from App2 through `SomeClient.java` exposed by App1. APP1 is **EJB** application.

App1 gives container supplied transaction as below.

```
InitialContext initialContext = someClientReference.getInitialContext();
UserTransaction tx = (UserTransaction)initialContext.lookup("UserTransaction");
```

Now App2 which is in tomcat also contains some **spring/Hibernate** logic. 
Now can i use above obtained **UserTransaction** in App2 to manage spring/hibernate persistence logic?

Thanks!